# Two-way ANOVA or mixed models

Tags: anova, mixed-model

I wonder if two-way ANOVA or other mixed-models are to prefer for my analysis.

Short background: The effect of three different treatments on parasites on leaves was measured over time (7 sampling dates). Different leaves have been used every sampling so the subject should be independent. I wish to see the effect of treatment (fixed, 3 levels) and date(random, 7 levels) on the amount of parasites. I have 7 samples per date and treatment but use averaged values. I have troubles conducting the two-way ANOVA in R using both random and fixed effects. If anyone have suggestions for this I would love any help!

Very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This is requires mixed model, because you have a between and a within-subject factor.

Comment: Thanks Janosch! Can I use a two-way ANOVA with mixed-effects (as one random and one fixed factor) or should i use lme/r?

Comment: You can use  `anova_test()`, which has an argument `wihtin=` with which you can include the within effect

Comment: Thanks again Janosch! I guess the within argument of date is treated as a random factor when I use it within?! I do not quite understand how this differs from repeated measures ANOVA.

Comment: A repeated meassures ANOVA with a fixed factor is the same. People just like to give it different names

Comment: Ok clarifies alot! Thank you once again!